# Как в angularjs передаются параметры в функцию

Tags: javascript, angularjs

К примеру из такого кода:

```
angular.module("sampleApp", [])
        .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $interval) {}
```

Angular узнает параметры функции через `.toString()`: $scope, $interval
А как потом он передает эти параметры `$scope, $interval` в функцию, что они доступны как переменные(параметры), а не как массив параметров?

Comment: [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)?

Comment: @Other а можно какой-то пример?

Comment: @Other а все разобрался! apply принимает массив параметров... и передает их как аргументы по отдельности! понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
let controller = fn => {
  let data = {
      $scope: 'Я scope!',
      $interval: 'Я interval'
  }
  
  if(typeof fn !== 'function')
    return;
  
  let args = fn.toString().split('{')[0].split('(')[1].replace(')', '').split(',').map(e => e.trim() in data ? data[e.trim()] : null);
  
  fn.apply(null, args);
}

controller(function($scope, $interval){
console.info($scope, $interval);
});
```

Comment: [немного сложнее](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/07849779ba365f371a8caa3b58e23f677cfdc5ad/src/auto/injector.js), но суть та же

Comment: @Grundy, поэтому и написал "Примерно так", а не "Вот так".